# What test do I use comparing pre and post intervention data?

Tags: interpretation

I am doing a health related project at at hospital where a policy was implemented for patients on certain therapy. Data was collected for the number of patients and days of therapy pre-implementation, then data was collected for the same interval of time post-implementation. How should I go about data analysis?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZt4m.jpg

Comment: Why don't you post your data to an excel file ( or a simulation of that )and we will try and help you. If you don't want to post your real data then simply code/scale it .

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your data, but if not, tell us what the outcome measure is and what other variables you wish to include in the analysis. Is the outcome measured twice for each patient?

Comment: I recently uploaded a link to imgur with my data!

Comment: can't understand/read your link .

Comment: Would the pre intervention be my control group?

Answer (score 5):

More detail would be helpful. Is days of therapy the outcome you are interested in examining? Are the actual patients the same pre- and post-intervention or are they different groups of patients? If the former, then you have a within-subjects design, and you could use ANOVA. If the groups are different then you'd probably want to consider something like a simple t-test to see whether the groups significantly differ on the outcome.